# Install Google Chrome on Loki

Tags: software-installation

I am the user of Elementary OS Luna, and was quiet satisfied with it. Yesterday I heard of `Loki` and wanted to give it a try. and it's cool.

But I found some weird issue of library missing while installing some `.deb` packages.

I couldn't install `atom text-editor` `upwork time tracking app` and `Google Chrome` due to some dependency missing problem.

Below I have attached the error screenshot while installing `Google Chrome Stable`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to install GDebi (sudo apt-get install gdebi) and open and install the .deb with GDebi.

Answer (score 1):

Just do `sudo apt -f install` after this. `dpkg -i` or `dpkg --install` doesn't install dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On a new install/upgrade:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Download the .deb from Google.com/Chrome (Note: Chrome is 64-bit only on Linux)
Select the download and go from there; or navigate to your 'files' (Applications > Files > Downloads (OR Windows/Command key + Space and type files)) and launch the installer (Click 'Install Package').